# Travel and Shacharit

Tags: tefilla, zemanim, travel, shacharis-morning-prayer

I'm flying westward in the morning. I don't think I'll have enough time to pray *shacharit* before I take off, and don't wish to do so en route. I should land with enough time to pray *shacharit* before *zman kriat shma*: is there any problem with my doing so? What would other issues of tefillah be in this case?

Comment: Why do you think it might be a problem?

Comment: I have no clue.

Comment: Do you think the zman will pass in the east but when you land in the west won't have passed, or do you just not have time in the east because of logistics?

Comment: Both. It turned out that I completely missed the zman because I was under the impression that my flight was two hours earlier than it was. I certainly had no time to daven, at least with tallit and tefillin beforehand though.

Answer (score 1):

Happens to me all the time. Two main issues I see

- Once the time to pray arrives, you cannot eat before you pray (see e.g., [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Eating_before_Davening) and [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/mon_10_31_11/)), which is one incentive to pray on the plane
- Planes are often delayed, or you can get stuck on the runway waiting to get off, therefore it is not a good idea to wait until the last minute to pray at the destination airport

If you cannot pray with *talit* and *tfilin* on the plane, one not-ideal possibility is to pray without on the plane, and put *talit*/*tfilin* later, either after arriving or at *mincha*.